How to reinstall a ceiling fan that fell out of ceiling?
So my ceiling fan fell off. I’ve never worked on one so I was wondering if anyone can kind of give me guidance on how to fix this. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.


What is above that hole in the ceiling?

Your ceiling fan was attached to an electrical box not rated for a fan and obviously not anchored to any framing member.  (looks like it was an old works light box that was only clamped to the drywall.)
You will need to find if a framing member is somewhere close around that hole.
You could possible use an extendable bar fan box These can have the bar slipped into the hole and expanded between the joists or trusses or whatever framing members you have. The bar expands and grips the wood and you then attach the box to the bar. Get one rated for a ceiling fan.
Do all the work with the power to the fan off.
Of course the electric cable needs to be transferred to the new box and the fan disassembled to the point that you can get to the fan mount and start the process to hang the fan over again.

Confirmation from NEC https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#314.27_(C)

They might as well cut a 2x2' square out with the amount of damage done already to install the right box/bar.    I wouldn't trust the boxes where they "grab".   First they can come loose and second unless you understand how to install them and how they feel when installed right its a crapshoot.    More than likely you will have a wobbly fan.    Kudos to the person who mad the wire nuts wrapped tight so this didn't hit the floor... at least they get some points after install it on an obviously wrong box.
